# Textarea instead input text API Platform

Tags: php, symfony, swagger, api-platform.com

I'm using api-platform 2.5 in a Symfony 5.1 project.

I want to implement multipart/form-data in API Platform as here in this doc https://api-platform.com/docs/core/file-upload/

Basically you just need to add:

```php
*   "openapi_context"={
*      "requestBody"={
*          "content"={
*              "multipart/form-data"={
*                  "schema"={
*                      "type"="object",
*                      "properties"={
*                          "file"={
*                              "type"="string",
*                              "format"="binary"
*                          }
*                      }
*                  }
*              }
*          }
*      }
*  }
```

which works perfectly.

I can also add an input text like this:

```php
*   "openapi_context"={
*      "requestBody"={
*          "content"={
*              "multipart/form-data"={
*                  "schema"={
*                      "type"="object",
*                      "properties"={
*                          "file"={
*                              "type"="string",
*                              "format"="binary"
*                          },
*                          "type"={
 *                             "type"="string"
 *                         }
*                      }
*                  }
*              }
*          }
*      }
*  }
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Now instead of having a text input, I would like to have a textarea with a default value.
Something like:

```php
*   "openapi_context"={
*      "requestBody"={
*          "content"={
*              "multipart/form-data"={
*                  "schema"={
*                      "type"="object",
*                      "properties"={
*                          "file"={
*                              "type"="string",
*                              "format"="binary"
*                          },
*                          "type"={
*                             "type"="textarea",
*                             "value"='{"some":"json-value"}',
*                         }
*                      }
*                  }
*              }
*          }
*      }
*  }
```

But I can't find a way to do this on their documentation.

Comment: Is the `type` field always a JSON object or is it arbitrary text?

Comment: It can be JSON or arbitrary text. With in fact are both string.
I just want to display a textarea